# Run Powershell Script from Sharepoint page

Tags: 2013, powershell, script

I use a PS script to create a list. Instead of a scheduled task, I wondered if I can put a link or a button on a sharepoint page, that when you click on it, it runs a PS Script on the SharePoint server (with Administrator privilege).

I saw [this](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/) plugin that allows us to run PS script within a workflow. This is a cool thing. But I prefer running the script whenever I want (or my users want).

Do you have a good reference for this ? I saw [this one](http://geekswithblogs.net/Norgean/archive/2012/09/19/running-powershell-from-within-sharepoint.aspx). But not sure about what I should Googled.

**NEW EDIT :**

Hey, I'm back.

I manage to create a empty projet thanks to [this](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.fr/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html).

So now, from my workstation (not SP server), I'm able to use PS script or commands. I also manage to use a dropdown list and select which script I want to execute.

I can't find how to add this **custom** application on my SP site (I have a aspx page, and aspx.cs). Well a kind of WebApplication if I'm right.

Comment: you want to hard code the script in C# or you want to load the script dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a Custom WebPart.
A simple button Handler could execute the under given code to fire your PowerShell script.

**scriptText** parameter is the script which you should pass. You can HardCode it or load it from any file.

```
private string RunScript(string scriptText)
{
    // create Powershell runspace

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

    // open it

    runspace.Open();

    // create a pipeline and feed it the script text

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

    // add an extra command to transform the script
    // output objects into nicely formatted strings

    // remove this line to get the actual objects
    // that the script returns. For example, the script

    // "Get-Process" returns a collection
    // of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

    // execute the script

    Collection<psobject /> results = pipeline.Invoke();

    // close the runspace

    runspace.Close();

    // convert the script result into a single string

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C)

Please let me know if you want further clarification.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: This is an answer. But now, I'm not enable to add this custom application in my SP test site. **Updated question**

Answer (score 0):

Very important addition. This command dont launch without next edits:

1. This code need use in
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() { // code above });
2. The account under which the portal is launched must have rights, in particular, be in the group "Recipient manager"