# Executing PowerShell script from SharePoint 2013 WebPart

Tags: development, powershell, sharepoint-addin

I've been trying to execute my powershell code from a  button click on a SharePoint Webpart. I came across this solution on a forum post.

```
private string RunScript(string scriptText){

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

// open it

runspace.Open(); //This is where it errors out.

// create a pipeline and feed it the script text

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

// add an extra command to transform the script
// output objects into nicely formatted strings

// remove this line to get the actual objects
// that the script returns. For example, the script

// "Get-Process" returns a collection
// of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

// execute the script

Collection<psobject /> results = pipeline.Invoke();

// close the runspace

runspace.Close();

// convert the script result into a single string

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
}

return stringBuilder.ToString();}
```

[Run Powershell Script from Sharepoint page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105905/run-powershell-script-from-sharepoint-page)

I've added the code from the above post to a Webpart solution but i keep running into the following error on the `runspace.Open()` line.

> System.Security.SecurityException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233078
>   Message=Requested registry access is not allowed.
>   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
>      at System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(String variable,     EnvironmentVariableTarget target)
>   at System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics.GetExpandedEnvironmentVariable(String name, EnvironmentVariableTarget target)
>   at System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics.SetModulePath()
>   at System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext.InitializeCommon(AutomationEngine engine, PSHost hostInterface)
>   at System.Management.Automation.AutomationEngine..ctor(PSHost hostInterface, RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration, InitialSessionState iss)
>   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace.DoOpenHelper()
>   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.CoreOpen(Boolean syncCall)
>   at TestWebPart.Project.Project.ExecuteCode_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

I've tried running the code under an impersonation block but that didn't seem to help.

Any ideas/suggestions on fixing this error will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    RunScript("xxx");
});
```

to get privileges